# Kubernetes Backend Pods Keep crashing and go into CrashLoopBackOff

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I have deployed a  node js  Application on K8  1.16 version.I notice that post deployment the backend pods keep crashing and going into CrashLoopBackOff, when I see the pod logs they dont give me much information :

```
> kubectl logs backend-mypod-backend-687bd47454-7dd6j

    copying .env from secret
    /opt/app-root/src/secret/.env.deploy found, copying to [/opt/app-root/src/.env]
    Start backend...
    
    > backend@1.1.1 start /opt/app-root/src
    > node lib/index.js
    
    >
```

The node application within the pod tries to do an - npm start but then the pod just crashes. I want to figure out any logs which can help me tell why the application keeps crashing. But I dont not clearly know how or which log to look at.

Can any one pls help or suggest the best way to debug this.

UPDATE:

Also I realized that - End Points for the Backend Pods also show up as BLANK :

```
kubectl describe svc
Name:              backend-XX-backend-svc
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          chart=backend-XX-backend,tier=backend
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                192.168.246.12
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        8800/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Any more thoughts  as to why this may be the case.

Comment: share dockerfile and kubernetes pod yaml

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu - Is there a log I can look at as well.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/generating-and-locating-npm-debug.log-files

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu - unfortunately by the time i login to the pod to access the debug log the pod gets killed

Comment: it's hard to help u if you don't share the details..does it work outside kubernetes ?

Comment: do a `kubectl describe`. You may get more info

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review the official k8s documentation on [how to troubleshoot applications](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/).

Answer (score 0):

You can acess [audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/audit-logging) in your Google Kubernetes Enigne clusters.

There you can find what are the source of the problems on your cluster.